# Receiving Facebook app error alerts - invalid parameters for "plugin:post"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, plugins

Starting on July 30th, and every 3 days since, we've been getting this alert for our Facebook app, which is used on our site for Facebook Login and social posting:

```
In the last three hours 100% of the calls to the method plugin:post
resulted in errors. 
Error Code  100 
Error Description   Invalid parameter
Error Count 5,971
```

Thing is, I have no idea what "plugin:post" is.  Google and stackoverflow don't seem to know either, for that matter :)  And 5,971 instances of it in 3 hours is more traffic than I would expect on our site.

Our codebase does not contain any references to "plugin:post", so I'm assuming "plugin:post" is an alias for some other functionality within the Graph API.  I just don't know what.  Anyone have an idea?

I did see there there is social plugin which uses an "fb:post" FBML style tag (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/) that sounds like it could be related, but we don't use that plugin.

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

[Edit 9/13 for Azhar's question:]
I checked the July 2013 Breaking Changes, and nothing seemed like it would impact us.

[Edit 9/13 for Tobi's question:]

We're using:
- Open Graph API for social posting via the Feed dialog to either the user's news feed or a friend's news feed
- Facebook Login API to allow users to log into our site,
- Facebook Javascript api for geting user info (e.g. FB.api('/me'...), F.api('/me/friends'...), etc. ), and other data via FQL FB.api("/fql"...).  I've verified that none of the FQL statements are impacted by the July 2013 changes.

I would post some code, but we have a fair amount of FB-related Javascript on the site, and I'm not sure which is the one causing the problem.

Comment: this does sound like some breaking changes. you should probably check july 2013 breaking changes.

Comment: Are you using Open Graph actions for your "social posting"? If not, what exactly do you mean with "social posting"? Some code would maybe help as well...

Comment: AzharYousuf and @Tobi , I've added a few details to the post to hopefully address your questions.  Thanks for the responses, btw!

Comment: Kevin, I have run out of ideas with the given amount of info. If only you can post some code, that might help.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ Select your app > Insights "see all" > Developer > Activity & Errors – Any more info there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was all due to a naming conflict in the HTML of our page.  We had a page element with a class name of "fb-post".  Facebook apparently treats this a "fb:post".  Since our "fb-post" was not an actual FBML tag, it does not have the other parameters Facebook looks for in a post.  So Facebook started giving alerts.

I suspect this is due to a change on Facebook's part, as we've had these "fb-post" elements in place for years now, without issue.

Incidentally, this is also the case for any elements with a class name of "fb-name", as Facebook treats that as "fb:name".

Answer (score 6):

My Facebook app is receiving the exact same error message alerts from Facebook.  I have exhausted all possible solutions and investigated every aspect of my logic, and I have concluded this is a bug on Facebook's side until someone can prove otherwise.

I have ignored these alerts so far and there has been no impact to my website or my users.  Every integration point with Facebook works flawlessly using my personal Facebook account, test Facebook users and other non-admin users across all major browsers.  Nothing appears wrong or broken.

When I investigate my Facebook app's insights and look at the developer view for activity and errors, I see plugin:post failures for the current month but when I go back one month there are absolutely zero API errors and it says "No API Errors".  This is obviously wrong because I was getting alerts last month and this helps support my theory that the issue is on Facebook's side.