# Facebook App Error Alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I have an app that uses a Facebook App in two ways:

1) Allows people to login via facebook
2) Does requests to facebook pages and retrieves their posts.

I just got an email from facebook that says the following:

```
In the last three hours 100% of the calls to the method GET status resulted in errors.
Error Code
100
Error Description
Invalid parameter
Error Count
1844
```

I'm not seeing any errors in my logs, and I manually tested everything and all seems to be working correctly. There doesn't seem to be any way for me to view a log on facebooks end of the errors I am getting, I don't know what the `Invalid Parameter` is and I'm not sure the best way to go about debugging this. Any recommendations?

Comment: What calls are you making? Invalid parameter simply means you're making some API call with a parameter that no longer exists for that endpoint. Have you checked the changelog. Maybe your app has been upgraded to a newer version of the platform that has changed the parameters.

Comment: @SleepyPanda I believe I have fixed the issue, it was not endpoints changing but rather might have been my access token expiring. It would have been a lot easier to fix the issue if I had been able to see the actual facebook calls that were failing.

Comment: @SleepyPanda this issue has shown up again, after about 3 weeks of being good, with no change on my end. I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343108/receiving-facebook-app-error-alerts-invalid-parameters-for-pluginpost where the guy is just assuming it's a bug on facebooks end. I am too until I can determine otherwise.